# Unable to deploy database to Azure

Tags: sql, azure, cloud

I created ms sql database in SSMS 2012. Connected successfully to Azure and trying to deploy db to the cloud.

Encountering following errors:

Please see [screen shot](http://content.screencast.com/users/jeefo88/folders/screen%20shots/media/886e1525-c383-4305-a1ae-b306c3f1d8ad/2014-09-09_1531.png)

Numerous Usupported property errors — not supported when used as part of a data package

Comment: I would help if you could click on the errors links and add the info as part of your question.

Comment: there's kind of private info there. I added brief error message.

Comment: Also should I prepare something in Azure before deploying database?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely using a feature not supported in Azure SQL Database.  Please refer to this non supported features list to help you pinpoint the problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394115.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me too. In my case ,i changed the schema of a table after creating once for the first time. After deleting that table database deployed correctly. Usually this error occurs when validating schema fails.

Regards
MAnoj Bojja